# playframework debug mode DuplicateMemberException

Tags: playframework

I have been running my playframework for the last few days and decided to try out debug mode.  I simply ran play eclipsify and refreshed my java project and then right clicked playtmp.launch and run as, and then "Connect JPDA to my launch" and Debug as and the debugger connected(though I had to tweak suspend to 'y' in playtmp.launch to tell).

NOTE: Every time I launch I get "Errors exist in project" but there are no errors in my Problems tab????

sooo, then I hit the first page and I get the below exception :( :(
(last time I ran into this it was because I stuck the play jar in the lib folder so my eclipse would compile, but I moved it out of there alread AND it works with play.bat run)

```
06:24:49,376 INFO  ~ Listening for HTTP on port 9000 (Waiting a first request to start) ...
06:26:09,738 ERROR ~ 

@69ageogm6
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /register

Oops: UnexpectedException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer on controllers.Admin

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying play.CorePlugin@48ff2413 on controllers.Admin
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:511)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.enhance(ApplicationClasses.java:235)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:165)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:429)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:505)
    at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:618)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:198)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer on controllers.Admin
    at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:302)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:506)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.DuplicateMemberException: duplicate field: $home0
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.testExistingField(ClassFile.java:529)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.addField(ClassFile.java:515)
    at javassist.CtClassType.addField(CtClassType.java:1164)
    at javassist.CtClass.addField(CtClass.java:878)
    at play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer.enhanceThisClass(LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer.java:180)
    at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:297)
    ... 8 more
06:26:09,741 ERROR ~ 

@69ageogm7
Error during the 500 response generation

Template not found
The template errors/500.html does not exist.

play.exceptions.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found : errors/500.html
    at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:192)
    at play.server.PlayHandler.serve500(PlayHandler.java:783)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
06:26:10,195 ERROR ~ 

@69ageogm8
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /favicon.ico

Template not found
The template errors/404.html does not exist.

play.exceptions.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found : errors/404.html
    at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:192)
    at play.server.PlayHandler.serve404(PlayHandler.java:690)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
06:26:10,196 ERROR ~ 

@69ageogm9
Error during the 500 response generation

Template not found
The template errors/500.html does not exist.

play.exceptions.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found : errors/500.html
    at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:192)
    at play.server.PlayHandler.serve500(PlayHandler.java:783)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANSWER: my launch file was playtmp.launch while my project was renamed and checked in to CVS as premonitionx so it was using another project in eclipse called playtmp.  The launcher ONLY works for the specific project...if you rename it you can get screwed(I hate environments like that).